# Составить программу, позволяющую организовать в виде записей данные о товарах в магазине

Tags: pascalabc.net

Доброго времени суток!
Каждая запись должна содержать название товара, проданное его количество, цену (вводятся из файла) и выручку с продажи (вычисляется в программе как произведение цены на количество)
Программа должна:
1.  Считать из файла информацию о N товарах и вывести данные на экран в виде таблицы;
2.  В записи с заданным названием товара изменить проданное количество на величину, введённую с клавиатуры;
3.  Вывести на экран обновлённую таблицу;
4.  Вывести на экран суммарную выручку с продажи и название самого прода-ваемого товара (по количеству). Если таких товаров несколько, то вывести название первого из них.
Текстовый документ формата txt:

**Banana        1500    10000
Aple         2000   15000
Mandarin    2200    20000 
Orange      2100    19000
Kiwi        1000    70000
Ananas      1200    90000
Lemon       3000    30000
Radish      2500    20000**

Comment: Так чего жы вы ждёте? За дело!

Comment: Не силен в математическом программировании, посоветуйте пожалуйста алгоритм решения задачи.

Comment: Вы не знаете, как умножить цену на количество? Не верю.